# Random G: Local Disk appeared, 3725gb in size and tells me the disk is unreadable

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive

On my computer, I have a Local disk C: drive (465gb) and an additional D: drive (7.27tb), running Windows 10.

I turned on my computer yesterday and file explorer immediately opened up with the notification "Cannot read or open G: drive". I do not have a G: drive, so this was confusing.

I restarted my PC and upon restart it attempted to repair the drive before booting up. "Repairing G: Drive". This was stuck on 2% for 12+ hours before I turned it off.

After restarting again, the G: drive was gone. However, it comes back randomly, every 2 or 3 restarts.

This 'ghost' G: Drive says it is size 3725gb and has RAW file system, 100% free space. I can see it on the Disk Management program, but I can't open it or anything.

The only performance issues when the mysterious G: drive appears is that certain programs are extremely slow (that normally are not), my PC has 32gb of RAM. I have all  my programs on my C: drive and they are not demanding programs, and have had no issues in the past.

It is annoying because my PC gets stuck on the 2% when repairing this mysterious G: drive everytime that it occurs when I am turning on my PC.

What is causing this issues? I can't seem to figure it out and there are not any posts online about this issue.

Thank you

Comment: Did you install any software lately? Some software installs a virtual drive, only way to get rid of it is to uninstall the software that out it there.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a recovery or other type of hidden partition that is being assigned a drive letter by Windows. You can remove the drive letter to keep it from appearing in Windows Explorer.

### Remove Drive Letter Assignment

Click on the windows Start button, type cmd, then right-click the first result (named Command Prompt), and choose 'Run as Administrator'

In the command window that appears, type the following and press enter:

```
diskpart
```

The Microsoft Diskpart Utility opens.

Type the following and press enter

```
list volume
```

In your case, you should see an entry that has G in the Ltr (letter) column.

To select the volume in the Diskpart utility, type the following and press enter

```
select volume g
```

To remove the drive letter that windows has assigned to this volume, type the following and press enter

```
remove letter=g
```

You can now close the command prompt window and restart your PC to complete the drive letter removal.